# Is it possible to define a function with more than one set amount of parameters in Python?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

I would like to define a function that takes two arguments, with the possibility of a third. 
I'm fairly certain this isn't possible, but considering the built-in `range` function has:

```
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object
```

Maybe it's possible? Or maybe I have the wrong idea because `range` is actually an immutable sequence type?

For clarity's sake, the same function `example(x,y)` could be run like `example(x,y,z)`

Comment: "I'm fairly certain this isn't possible" - did you try reading the [official tutorial's section on defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)? I'm curious about how much research you actually did.

Comment: About 6 minutes of searching through stack exchange and zero tutorial reading.

Comment: Although I have to admit, I didn't think about using the keywords 'optional' while searching. My fault entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
def example(x, y, z=None):
    if z is None:
        return x + y
    else:
        return x + y + z
```

then

```
>>> example(3, 4)
7

>>> example(3, 4, 5)
12
```

Comment: that's it! thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through `default` arguments (sometimes called `keyword` arguments)...

```
def example(x, y, z=None):
    ...
```

In the function, you'd check if `z is None` to see if it was provided.

You can also use `*args` here:

```
def example(x, y, *args):
    ...  # *args is a tuple of all of the rest of the positional arguments.
```

Here, you could use the `len(args)` to determine if the third argument was passed.